# Is There A Way To Force Customers To Only Checkout With Billing Address?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

On one of my sites, we sell high value items, and to protect against fraud, we need to make sure we only ship to the billing address.

Is there a way of disabling the shipping address option? This will need to support a multi-store installation, as the other sites on the installation sell lower value items that are ok to send to alternative addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The following article provides information on how to restrict checkout to the billing address only.

http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/disable-shipping-address-in-magento-checkout/

Comment: Thanks. I saw that, but it appears some of the code is missing (for example, the 'here is the layout file' box is completely empty) - plus it doesn't say anything about multi-store installations.

I found this as well: http://www.designhaven.co.uk/2014/09/force-customers-checkout-billing-address-disabling-shipping-address/#comment-31614

But this one definitely doesn't support multi-store...

Comment: You should be able to download the completed source code at the end of the article which you can download and walk through.

Comment: There's a download link - I didn't see that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to let magento think that you have in quote only virtual items, even you have simple or some another.

Other way I can recommend one 3rd party module, which can disable any checkout step